# referential Integrity and complicated joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
A27,346467413,68723601
A28,346467414,68723601
A28,346467416,68723601
A27,349454768,8908697809
A28,349454769,8908697809
A28,349454771,8908697809
```

I have the above sample from a table I need to do some mind boggling sql on. Basically whats been asked of me is that for each A27, two proceeding A28 belong to that A27 and the information need to be tied together. However, I have been asked to create a table for each A_Number so A27 will be in its own table and A28 will be in its own table two. What I need to do is do a Join on them so each A27 can link to its corresponding A28 that follow after it.  Just wondering how I would go about it if it were in separate tables and what the Join and SQL would look like? Keep in mind non of the data makes any sense as its invoice reconciliation stuff.

[image]

I have uploaded the sample file attached

[image]

Comment: Bit confusing please post expected output and mention column names.

Comment: From your description there is nothing in the table data that links a parent (A27) to a child (A28) other than proximity.  In Oracle data retrieval is non-deterministic - the order the data is retrieved will change unless you specify an order by.  You don't have a key you can use to order so that will be a problem.  Perhaps SQL Server is different.

Comment: Assuming that you *can* reliably link a parent to a child then you need to assign an ID to each parent and reference this on the child.  Insert the data into your two tables and the join is trivial

Comment: I agree with Christian that order could be an issue in sql-server too.  But I just noticed column 3 appears to be unique for the combinations of A27 and 2 A28 records following (not preceeding).  Is that your key?  You could use Col 3 to relate and a row_number() on col2???? desired results and columns would be helpful!

Comment: I have added the sample above if you could please have a look.

Comment: There are no headers in the text files, just values

Comment: Please put the expected result also

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: lol at above comment, its something that I was asked to do but I haven't been given any expected output of what the result should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
       *
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Column2) AS RowNumber
    FROM
       @Table
)

SELECT
     *
    ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY A27.Column2) as GroupingId
FROM
    cte A27
    LEFT JOIN cte A28
    ON A28.RowNumber IN (a27.RowNumber + 1, a27.RowNumber + 2)
    AND A28.Column1 = 'A28'
WHERE
    A27.Column1 = 'A27'
```

Because based on your image `Column3` isn't unique to only the row numbers you want I didn't go the route of using it.  Instead I used a `ROW_NUMBER` based on `Column2` which appears to be an increment primary key and then simply `LEFT SELF JOIN`. This is for the 2 A28 rows `AFTER` each A27 Row.  if you want "`preceding`" like your OP says but doesn't suggest then simply reverse it by changing the `JOIN` condition:

```
ON A28.RowNumber IN (a27.RowNumber - 1, a27.RowNumber - 2)
```

*Note I did add a `GroupingID` to give you way of identifying which A27 and A28's are together it could be used as a new primary key in your A27 table and a foreign key in your A28 table to preserve the relationship.*

Here is the test data I used.

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (Column1 CHAR(3), Column2 BIGINT, Column3 BIGINT)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES
('A27',346467408,68723601)
,('A28',346467409,68723601)
,('A28',346467411,68723601)
,('A27',346467413,68723601)
,('A28',346467414,68723601)
,('A28',346467416,68723601)
,('A27',349454768,8908697809)
,('A28',349454769,8908697809)
,('A28',349454771,8908697809)
```

**Edit**: As per your comment of how to do it when in separate tables.  You can use a union all to combine the tables:

```
DECLARE @A27 AS TABLE (Column1 CHAR(3), Column2 BIGINT, Column3 BIGINT)
DECLARE @A28 AS TABLE (Column1 CHAR(3), Column2 BIGINT, Column3 BIGINT)
INSERT INTO @A27 VALUES
('A27',346467408,68723601)
,('A27',346467413,68723601)
,('A27',349454768,8908697809)
INSERT INTO @A28 VALUES
('A28',346467409,68723601)
,('A28',346467411,68723601)
,('A28',346467414,68723601)
,('A28',346467416,68723601)
,('A28',349454769,8908697809)
,('A28',349454771,8908697809)

;WITH cteUnion AS (
    SELECT
       Column1, Column2, Column3
    FROM
       @A27

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
       Column1, Column2, Column3
    FROM
       @A28
)

, cteRowNum AS (
    SELECT * ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Column2) AS RowNumber
    FROM
       cteUnion
)

SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY a27.Column2) as GroupingId
FROM
    cteRowNum a27
    LEFT JOIN cteRowNum a28
    ON a28.RowNumber IN (a27.RowNumber + 1, a27.RowNumber + 2)
    AND a28.Column1 = 'A28'
WHERE
    a27.Column1 = 'A27'
```

If the tables are larger or performance may be an issue you might want to build a temp table and do it that way.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Combined') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #Combined
    END

CREATE TABLE #Combined (
    TableName CHAR(3)
    ,Column2 BIGINT
)

INSERT INTO #Combined (TableName, Column2)
SELECT Column1, Column2
FROM
    @A27

INSERT INTO #Combined (TableName, Column2)
SELECT Column1, Column2
FROM
    @A28

;WITH cteRowNum AS (
    SELECT * ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Column2) AS RowNumber
    FROM
       #Combined
)

SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY a27.Column2) as GroupingId
FROM
    cteRowNum a27
    LEFT JOIN cteRowNum a28
    ON a28.RowNumber IN (a27.RowNumber + 1, a27.RowNumber + 2)
    AND a28.TableName = 'A28'
WHERE
    a27.TableName = 'A27'
```

Comment: Thank you Matt, this does help alot, I am trying to replicate what you have done but the values of A28 and A27 are in their own tables respectively, so I can't seem to get the right results that you have when querying two tables. How would you go about doing it?

Comment: @abs786123 You can use a union all and merge the tables or a temp table.  I have updated the answer.  If the answer satisfies your needs please mark it as accepted so that others know you have a solution and reputation points are awarded.  Thanks

Comment: Thank you again Matt, what if the columns in table a27 and a28 have different data types in the columns requested to be shown. Any way around that as the two above will depend on the datatypes being the same across the result sets?

Comment: @abs786123 just cast or convert them to the same datatype so that they match in the union and of in the temp table

Comment: Thank you Matt, just added another piece on top of my post which now involves using A99 as well with with the A27 and A28. Just wondering, got feedback with regards to what I need, feedback was "Your simple +1,+2 will not work in this instance.  Also are you guaranteeing that SSIS is processing the file in order and not in 1000 row batches which mean that the rows could be out of order". any way around that. Sorry to keep pestering you but not dealt with data like this before in this way.

Comment: @abs786123  you should open new questions at this point rather than continuing to append additional questions to this post.  and for row number method to work you would need to stage the data in sql outside of SSIS, SSIS would take scripting and the batching could mess it up and likely to be non performant.  However none of that matters in your image above that contains the 99 shows that the data has a self referencing foreign key in other words your FileFK relates to FilePK so you don't need any of these techniques simply use that relationship its already in place.

Answer (score 1):

Best guess given lack of formatted output...

- I used a CTE (Common table Expression) for the data set and a a cte to generate the row numbers for each set.
- I used left joins as I don't know if there will always be 3 rows.
- I assumed col3 was a unique identifier for each group/partition.
- I assumed col2 value will always be lowest for A27.
- I use Row_number to number the rows for each partition

.

```
WITH dataset as (
SELECT 'A27' as Col1,346467413 as col2,68723601 as col3 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A28' as Col1,346467414 as col2,68723601 as col3 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A28' as Col1,346467416 as col2,68723601 as col3 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A27' as Col1,349454768 as col2,8908697809 as col3 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A28' as Col1,349454769 as col2,8908697809 as col3 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A28' as Col1,349454771 as col2,8908697809 as col3),

CTE AS 
(SELECT col1, col2, col3, row_number() over (partition by col3 order by col2) rn
FROM dataset)

SELECT A.Col1, A.Col3, A.Col2, B.Col2 as, C.Col2 
FROM cte A
LEFT JOIN cte B
 on A.Col3 = B.Col3 and A.Rn= 1 and b.rn = 2
LEFT JOIn cte C
 on A.Col3 = C.Col3 and A.RN =1 and c.RN = 3
```

This should result in a flat output that could then be placed into separate tables as needed.